# Connecting Unity3d with Node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use socket.io to connect my unity3d program with node.js server.

Using the UnitySocketIO, I succeeded the connection between the client and server.

However, On or Emit method does not work.

Can someone help me with this problem?

```
void Start () {

    string socketUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:50122";
    Debug.Log("socket url: " + socketUrl);

    this.socket = new Client(socketUrl);
    this.socket.Opened += this.SocketOpened;
    this.socket.Message += this.SocketMessage;
    this.socket.SocketConnectionClosed += this.SocketConnectionClosed;
    this.socket.Error += this.SocketError;

    this.socket.Connect();
}

private void SocketOpened (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Debug.Log("socket opened");                  // i got this message
    this.socket.On ("message", (data) => {
        Debug.Log ("message : " + data);
    });
    this.socket.Emit("join", "abc"); 
    Debug.Log("Emit done");                  // i got this message
}
```

....

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log('connect');                  // i got this message

    socket.emit('message', 'Hello World!');

    socket.on('join', function (id) {
        console.log('client joined with id ' + id);
        socket.emit('message', 'Hello ' + id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Got this working? Struggling with this myself.

Comment: Did you solve this in the end? Where did you put the dll files of the UnitySocketIO?

Comment: @Nikola, just put the dll files anywhere inside your Assets folder.  Then (for c#) just add `using SocketIOClient;` to your script.  I'm not sure what the equivalent is for javascript but can't be hard to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

Your event probably attached in wrong order, try like this:

```
void Start() {
    string socketUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:50122";
    Debug.Log("socket url: " + socketUrl);

    this.socket = new Client(socketUrl);
    this.socket.Opened += this.SocketOpened;
    this.socket.Message += this.SocketMessage;
    this.socket.SocketConnectionClosed += this.SocketConnectionClosed;
    this.socket.Error += this.SocketError;

    this.socket.On("message", (data) => {
        Debug.Log("message: " + data);
    });

    this.socket.Connect();
}
```

And for node:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('client connected');
  socket.emit('message', 'Hello World!');
});
```

As well do not allow client to decide own ID, as it is "hackable" in most cases. Only server should make important decisions and not client.

Comment: Thanks for help, but the log for 'message' still doesn't come up.

Comment: You might want to minimize your example totally, in order to easier to debug and find out how it works, and then implement to your Unity application.