# unity3D: connect to node.js using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use socket.io to connect my unity3d program with node.js server. Is it possible?if it possible, please share the documents or steps of this....

Most of the people used  "unity socket.io" to connect unity3d program with node.js server. I found a question in SO [Connecting Unity3d with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568066/connecting-unity3d-with-node-js) for unity socket.io. But I need for socket.io.
how to install this module. Please share this........

Comment: socket.io is designed for the WebSocket (ws://) protocol. So if you want to use it, you'll need a WebSocket client library for unity. You can also use classic sockets on unity side and `require('net').Socket` on the node side. http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket

Answer (score 2):

There are some libraries available which I've been meaning to try, the most promising of which being [NetEase](https://github.com/NetEase/UnitySocketIO)

You may want to give that a try.